# ValueError creating a constraint in Cplex

Tags: python, cplex, or-tools

Need to write this code wrote using Ortools, in cplex, but every time I tried to set the coefficients i got this error:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
(' invalid matrix input type -- ', range(0, 1))
  File "C:\Users\rodri\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Projeto Teste\teste.py", line 111, in create
    solver.linear_constraints.add(
  File "C:\Users\rodri\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Projeto Teste\main.py", line 19, in criar_e_otimizar_dados
    otimizacao.create()
ValueError: (' invalid matrix input type -- ', range(0, 1))
```

This is my code:

```
        # Criando a variável x inteira com 3 dimensões
        print("Criando variaveis")
        x = {}
        for i in carteiras.keys():
            x[i] = {}
            for j in carteiras.keys():
                if troca_possivel(i, j):
                    x[i][j] = {}
                    for k in carteiras[i].posicoes.keys():
                        if posicao_nao_excedeu_limite(i, j, k):
                            x[i][j][k]=solver.variables.add(lb=[0], ub=[carteiras[i].posicoes[k].quantidade], names=[f'x[{i}][{j}][{k}]'])
                            
        # Restricao 1: Integridade
        print("Criando Restrições de Integridade")
        for i in carteiras.keys():
            for k in carteiras[i].posicoes.keys():
                solver.linear_constraints.add(range_values=[-cplex.infinity, carteiras[i].posicoes[k].quantidade])
                for j in carteiras.keys():
                    if troca_possivel(i, j) and posicao_nao_excedeu_limite(i, j, k):
                        solver.linear_constraints.add(
                            lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=[x[i][j][k]], val=[1])],
                            names=[f'integridade_{i}_{k}'],
                            rhs=[carteiras[i].posicoes[k].quantidade],
                            senses=["L"]
                        )
```

Tried everything, just want a way to set the coefficients

Comment: It is difficult to help as the error is not reproducible and the line which causes the error isn't clear.  You might need to either post more/all of your code so that someone can reproduce the error or whittle down your code to a minimal reproducible example which causes the error.  That said, it appears that the error *may* be caused because in some mystery line you are passing in a `range()` object, instead of a list or matrix.  Try to convert the `range()` object into a simple list by `list(range(...))` and see if that works